# Doctrine2 LEFT JOIN WITH producing unexpected result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got the following query:

```
<?php
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$data['ps'] = $em->createQuery('SELECT s,ps FROM AppBundle:Sucursales s LEFT JOIN AppBundle:ComprasProductosSucursales ps WITH s.id = ps.sucursal')->getResult();
```

But I get a result like in the following image:

![Example of Doctrine2 resultset][1]

I expected that `$data['ps'][1]` to be part of `$data['ps'][0]`, otherwise the iteration of the array is going to be very weird.

So, it's possible to get the result of the joined table  AppBundle:ComprasProductosSucursales as columns of the AppBundle:Sucursales data?

ORMs:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Sucursales:
    type: entity
    table: sucursales
# Note: no relations defined, deleting the rest of the columns for clarity

AppBundle\Entity\ComprasProductosSucursales:
    type: entity
    table: compras_productos_sucursales

manyToOne:
    producto:
        targetEntity: ComprasProductos
    sucursal:
        targetEntity: Sucursales
        cascade: {  }
```

Comment: Does your posted query really match your actual query because I don't see how it can be working at all.

Comment: Actually yes, it does produces de following SQL query:
`SELECT 
  s0_.id AS id0, 
  s0_.nombre AS nombre1, 
  s0_.telefono AS telefono2, 
  s0_.direccion AS direccion3, 
  s0_.activo AS activo4, 
  c1_.id AS id5, 
  c1_.cantidad_promedio AS cantidad_promedio6, 
  c1_.producto_id AS producto_id7, 
  c1_.sucursal_id AS sucursal_id8 
FROM 
  sucursales s0_ 
  LEFT JOIN compras_productos_sucursales c1_ ON (s0_.id = c1_.sucursal_id)`

Comment: And when I run that query in Workbench I get the desired results, 1 row for "Sucursal" data along with extra columns for "ComprasProductosSucursal" data if any, otherwise null

Comment: When using getScalarResult I get the exact result I'm looking for ([example](http://i.imgur.com/DzzFAz9.png)) but fields are prefixed by table alias, this can be ok though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your entities related then normally your DQL query would be something like:

```
  $dql <<<EOT
SELECT s,ps FROM AppBundle:Sucursales s 
LEFT JOIN s.ps ps
EOT;
```

Doctrine takes care of the with condition on the join and will give you a nested set of results.  The assumes that your Sucursales has a collection property called ps.  I guess I am also assuming that you are creating Doctrine 2 entities and have them related.

More info: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

Comment: Thank you, actually the relation is in ComprasProductosSucursal. I'll update the question with the relations. Also I don't have a collection named ps, it's the alias I've set for the entity ComprasProductosSucursal

Comment: Just change s.ps to s.whateverYouCalled it.

Comment: I've updated the question with the ORMs, I tried your change: `SELECT s FROM AppBundle:Sucursales s LEFT JOIN s.ComprasProductosSucursales ps` but I get: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'ps': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Sucursales has no association named ComprasProductosSucursales`

Comment: From your mapping it looks like you have a relation from ComprasProductosSucursales to Sucursales but not the other way around.  So doctrine will not understand the query.  You need to add the relation or select from ComprasProductosSucursales and join Sucursales.

Comment: I though about the second approach but I need this query to get all values from Sucursales and if there's corresponding values in ComprasProductosSucursales then get them, if not then show them values as null.